# Knockout Bindings are not being applied when using angular templates

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dukescript, angularjs-ng-template

I'm trying to port an angular example to dukescript and navigation behaves as spected, but when tried to apply bindings nothing happened.

I've tried both with the script tag an in external files with the same results and [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) bindings are not being applied.

Extract:

```
<script>
.
.
.

  <span style="float:left;" id="movimientos" data-bind="text:movimientos"></span>
.
.
.
<script>
```

Full code:

```
<html ng-app="proyecto" dir="ltr"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Puzzle Logic</title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/dashboard.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body contenteditable="true">
        <!-- animation="slide-left-right-ios7" class="platform-android platform-cordova platform-webview" -->
    <ion-nav-view> </ion-nav-view>
    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view>
    <ion-content padding="true" class="fondoDePaisaje">
        <a href="#/settings"><button class="button button-assertive icon ion-gear-a" style="float:right;"></button></a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!--logo-->
        <div id="logo" style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="img/logo_pusle.png" alt="Puzzle Land" width="300rem">

            <div id="botones_comienzo">
                <a href="#/dashboard" class="opcion_menu">
                    <span>J</span>
                    <span>u</span>
                    <span>g</span>
                    <span>a</span>
                    <span>r</span>
                </a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="#/score" class="opcion_menu">
                    <span>S</span>
                    <span>c</span>
                    <span>o</span>
                    <span>r</span>
                    <span>e</span>
                </a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="" class="opcion_menu">
                    <span>A</span>
                    <span>y</span>
                    <span>u</span>
                    <span>d</span>
                    <span>a</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <!--pie de pagina-->
        <div class="row-center" style="background-color:transparent; text-align: center;">
            <div>Derechos Reservados</div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
    </script>
    <script id="templates/dashboard.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view>
    <!-- ng-controller="CntrlDashboard" -->
    <ion-content class="fondoDePaisaje">
        <!--movimientos realizados-->
        <div class="mismovimientos">
            <span style="float:left;">Mov:</span>
            <span style="float:left;" id="movimientos" data-bind="text:movimientos"></span>

            <a href="" ng-click="nuevo()" style="float:right;" id="nuevo">Nuevo</a>
            <!--cronometro-->
            <span style="float:right; margin-rigth:10px; padding-right:20px;">T:<span id="minutos">0</span>:<span id="segundos">0</span></span>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

        <!--crearemos la tabla-->
        <div class="row tabla" id="tabla1">
            <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p1" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">1</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p2" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">2</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p3" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">3</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="3" id="p4" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">4</div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row tabla" id="tabla2">
            <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p5" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">5</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p6" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">6</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p7" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">7</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="3" id="p8" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">8</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tabla" id="tabla3">
            <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p9" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">9</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p10" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">10</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p11" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">11</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="3" id="p12" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row tabla" id="tabla4"> 
            <div class="col" posicion="0" id="p13" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">13</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="1" id="p14" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">14</div>
            <div class="col" posicion="2" id="p15" ng-click="mensaje( $event )">15</div>
            <div class="col vacio" posicion="3" id="p16" ng-click="mensaje( $event )"></div>
        </div>  

        <!--volver-->
        <div class="mismovimientos">
            <span style="float:left; font-size:16px !important;">Derechos Reservados</span>
            <a href="#/perfil" style="float:right;" id="nuevo">Volver</a>  
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>

    </ion-content><!--cierre del contenido-->
</ion-view>
    </script>
</body></html>
```

How can I fix it?

### Update

Did a test on dew and the results are that bindings are not applied inside the script tag.

**Test**
Java:

```
package dew.demo.ko4j;
import net.java.html.json.*;

@Model(className="Hello", properties={
  @Property(name="say", type=String.class)
})
class HelloViaKO {
  static {
    Hello model = new Hello("Hello World!");
    model.applyBindings();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
Test 1!
<div>
  <span style="float:left;" id="moves" data-bind="text: say">vxc</span>
</div>
Test2!
<script>
  <span style="float:left;" id="moves" data-bind="text: say">vxc</span>
</script>
Test3!
<script>
  <span style="float:left;" id="moves">hello</span>
</script>
```

The generated HTML is
[image: console output]
and the highighted part should be:

```
<script>
  <span style="float:left;" id="moves" data-bind="text: say">Hello World!</span>
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Why the -1 is my english that bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've switched to knockout for binding, so I'll update my answer:

Your DEW example tries to show that bindings are not applied inside script tags. But script tags are not rendered in the UI, so even if the bindings would be applied in your example, you wouldn't see it in the output.

Despite that, your assumption that they are not applied is correct. This is the expected and correct behavior. In Knockout, script tags can be used to define templates:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

In that case the template binding takes the active template script, inserts it at the chosen location and only then applies the bindings.

Comment: I jas just tryiing knockoutjs for the data binding but without results <span style="float:left;" id="movimientos" data-bind="text:movimientos"></span>